# Neo4j: skip nodes that have even just a single relationship matching a query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The scenario is the following:

- I have a set of nodes of type `x` that are linked to nodes of type `y`.
- I want to match all `x` nodes except those that are linked to a `y` node that has an attribute equal to a particular value.

Example input:

```
CREATE (a:x {name: 'a'}), (b:x {name: 'b'}), (c:x {name: 'c'});

CREATE (d:y {name: 'd', attrib: 1}), (e:y {name: 'e', attrib: 2}),
       (f:y {name: 'f', attrib: 3}), (g:y {name: 'g', attrib: 4}),
       (h:y {name: 'h', attrib: 5}), (i:y {name: 'i', attrib: 6});

MATCH (a), (d), (e) WHERE a.name = 'a' AND d.name = 'd' AND e.name = 'e'
CREATE (a)-[r:z]->(d), (a)-[s:z]->(e) RETURN *;

MATCH (b), (f), (g) WHERE b.name = 'b' AND f.name = 'f' AND g.name = 'g'
CREATE (b)-[r:z]->(f), (b)-[s:z]->(g) RETURN *;

MATCH (c), (h), (i) WHERE c.name = 'c' AND h.name = 'h' AND i.name = 'i'
CREATE (c)-[r:z]->(h), (c)-[s:z]->(i) RETURN *;
```

Here I want to return all the `x` nodes except those that are linked to a `y` node that has `attrib = 5`.

Here's what I tried:

```
MATCH (n:x)-[]-(m:y) WHERE NOT m.attrib = 5 RETURN n
```

From this query I get all `x` nodes, that is: `a`, `b` and `c`. I would like to exclude `c`, because it's linked to `h`, which has `h.attrib = 5`.

**Edit:**

I found a query that does the job:

```
MATCH (n:x), (m:x)-[]-(o:y)
WHERE o.attrib = 5
WITH collect(n) as all_x_nodes, collect(m) as bad_x_nodes
RETURN [n IN all_x_nodes WHERE NOT n IN bad_x_nodes]
```

The problem is that it's not efficient. Any better alternative?

Comment: Try a separate `collect` to avoid creating a Cartesian product:

`MATCH (n:x), WITH collect(n) as all_x_nodes
MATCH (m:x)-[]-(o:y {attrib: 5}) WITH collect(m) as bad_x_nodes
RETURN ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple query should do exactly what you asked for: "return all the `x` nodes except those that are linked to a `y` node that has `attrib = 5`."

```
MATCH (n:x)
WHERE NOT (n)--(:y {attrib: 5})
RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to find all :x nodes that you want to exclude (that are connected to the :y node with the specific attribute), collect those x nodes, then match to all :x nodes that aren't in the collection:

```
MATCH (exclude:x)--(:y{attrib:5})
WITH collect(distinct exclude) as excluded
MATCH (n:x)
WHERE NOT n in excluded
RETURN collect(n) as result
```

An alternate approach using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html) is to get both collections, and subtract the excluded collection from the other:

```
MATCH (exclude:x)--(:y{attrib:5})
WITH collect(distinct exclude) as excluded
MATCH (n:x)
WITH excluded, collect(n) as nodes
RETURN apoc.coll.subtract(nodes, excluded) as result
```

In either case, it would help to have an index on :y(attrib). In this data set it doesn't matter. On much larger sets it will.